# SQL query on relational schema

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to find the best solutions for operations on the following database:

```
  Employee (EmployeeId, Surname, Salary, DepartmentId)
  Department (DepartmentId, DeptName, City, Director)
  Project (ProjectId, ProjectName, Budget, Director)
  Works (EmpoyeeId, ProjectId)
```

My queries:

1 SQL query to find the surname of the employees who are directors of a department.

```
SELECT Surname
FROM Employee
WHERE Employee.EmployeeId IN (
SELECT Department.Director
FROM Department
);
```

2 SQL query to find the employee surname and salary of all employees who work in Haarlem.

```
SELECT Surname, Salary, City
FROM Employee,Department
WHERE Department.City = ‘Haarlem’;
```

3 SQL query to find the names of the projects whose budget is higher than 100 and the surnames of the employees who work on them.

```
SELECT ProjectName, Budget, Surname
FROM Project, Employee, Works
WHERE Project.Budget > 100
AND Works.EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId
AND Works.ProjectId = Project.ProjectId;
```

Are there any better ways to get the information needed?

Comment: Can anyone be a director of a department that's different to their department from the Employee table? Why don't you use a JOIN for the first query?

Comment: What flavour of SQL? They're unfortunately not all the same.

Answer (score 2):

1. ```
   SELECT Surname
   FROM Employee
   JOIN Department ON Department.Director = Employee.EmployeeId;
   ```

   Other than not requiring a subquery, this is generally a better thing to do because you can then easily access the matching `Department` table if you ever need to select a column from it.
2. Are you sure that this even works? You aren't joining the employee's department to the department ID. This should likely be:

   ```
   SELECT Surname, Salary, City
   FROM Employee
   JOIN Department ON Department.DepartmentId = Employee.DepartmentId
                  AND Department.City = 'Haarlem';
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT ProjectName, Budget, Surname
   FROM Employee
   JOIN Works ON Works.EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId
   JOIN Project ON Project.ProjectId = Works.ProjectId
               AND Project.Budget > 100;
   ```

   This should be functionally equivalent but uses cleaner syntax.